# how to map two same URLs with different params in springfox with springboot rest controller?

Tags: spring-boot, springfox

Below are the 2 RequestMapping handler methods in my rest controller with the same value but different param.

```
@ApiOperation(value = "Query with name", nickname = "queryWithNameParam")
    @RequestMapping(value = "/query", params = "name",
            method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public void queryWithNameParam()


@ApiOperation(value = "Query with code", nickname = "queryWithCodeParam")
@RequestMapping(value = "/query", params = "code",
        method = RequestMethod.GET)
public void queryWithCodeParam()
```

I am able to invoke both the methods using resttemplate, but the API is not being shown on the browser when accessing swagger-ui.html

I am using springboot 2.0.3.RELEASE and springfox 2.9.2

Comment: May help this link https://github.com/springfox/springfox/issues/1828

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Now there is only one option to fix this:

1. Add `springfox-swagger-ui-rfc6570` instead of `springfox-swagger-ui` as a dependency.
2. Set `enableUrlTemplating(true)` in your docket configuration.

Source:
http://springfox.github.io/springfox/docs/current/#springfox-rfc6570-support-strong-incubating-strong

Open issues in springfox Github project:

- https://github.com/springfox/springfox/issues/2354
- https://github.com/springfox/springfox/issues/2042

Closed issues:

- https://github.com/springfox/springfox/issues/2541
- https://github.com/springfox/springfox/issues/1874

Comment: Thanks mate!
https://github.com/springfox/springfox/issues/1874#issuecomment-317435669 helped in my case